# jQuery UI Slider change and slide events report different results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, anonymous-function, jquery-slider

Okay, so a very similar question was asked here

[jQuery UI Slider - Value returned from 'slide' event on release is different from 'change' value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121160/jquery-ui-slider-value-returned-from-slide-event-on-release-is-different-fro)

But the answer was unsatisfactory in my opinion. Here is my JavaScript code: http://jsfiddle.net/AsDZJ/4/

```js
function slideVal() {
    var number = $("#number_slider").slider("value");
    $("#number_field").append('Slide: ' + number + '<br/>');
}

function changeVal() {
    var number = $("#number_slider").slider("value");
    $("#number_field").append('Change: ' + number + '<br/>');
}

$(function() {
    $( "#number_slider" ).slider({
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        change: changeVal,
        slide: slideVal
    });

    $( "#number_slider" ).slider( "value", 5 );
});
```

The issue is that the slider is reporting different values between when the *change* handler is called, and when the *slide* handler is called.

Now, the other question points out that if you declare the function anonymously, you can simply use ui.value, like so:

```js
$( "#number_slider" ).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    change: function(event, ui) {
        $("#number_field").append('Change: ' + ui.value + '<br/>');
    }
});
```

This does give more consistent results, but also means that if, as in my case, I have a lot of complex logic to perform whenever the event changes, I have to repeat code. In addition, the calculations involve slider values from multiple sliders.

How can I get access to the correct value from an explicitly declared function? Is this behavior in jQuery UI a bug?

Thanks

Comment: Well, here is one solution. It seems pretty stupid to me, perhaps someone can provide a better answer.

I set some variables available to both scopes. Inside the anonymous event handler function I first set the appropriate 'global' variable using `ui.value`, then call the function that handles the calculation logic.
http://jsfiddle.net/AsDZJ/6/

Comment: Hi, i don't know if this will help but have you try use stop event and cross the results with the change event. I am saying this because final value in change should be the stop event value not the slide event, i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still define global functions with parameters, when you initialize the slider just pass in the function name instead of using an anonymous callbacks

```
function slideVal(e, ui) {
    var number = ui.value;
    $("#number_field").append('Slide: ' + number + '<br/>');
}

function changeVal(e, ui) {
    var number = ui.value;
    $("#number_field").append('Change: ' + number + '<br/>');
}

$(function() {
    $( "#number_slider" ).slider({
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        change: changeVal,
        slide: slideVal
    });

    $( "#number_slider" ).slider( "value", 5 );
});
```