# ui slider shows difference between moved value before and after mouse goes up

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, slider, tooltip

Please help me with this jquery-ui-slider!
The time value in the tooltip is created with the initial time values; the value changes through the way moving with the mouse from A to B; at B before mouse goes up, the value differs to the value that shows afterwards; with other words the script generates two values during sliding and stopping and when mouse goes up; the moved position B value differs slightly from the position B end value after mouse up;

a possible solution:
replace .slider("values", 0)... with ui.values[0]
[jQuery UI Slider - Value returned from 'slide' event on release is different from 'change' value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121160/jquery-ui-slider-value-returned-from-slide-event-on-release-is-different-fro)

is it a solution and how can we do this for this slider? 
have someone an idea? please help!

> //jquery ui slider with two tooltips shows seconds
>
> ```
> $(function() {
>  var initialTime1 = 28800;
>  var initialTime2 = 57600;
> ```
>
> //object with html-tooltip and value in seconds
>
> ```
> var valtooltip = function(sliderObj, ui){
> val1 = '<span class="slider-tip">'+sliderObj.slider("values", 0) + '</span>';
> val2 = '<span class="slider-tip">'+sliderObj.slider("values", 1) + '</span>';
> sliderObj.find('.ui-slider-handle:first').html(val1);
> sliderObj.find('.ui-slider-handle:last').html(val2);                   
> };
>
> $("#slider_time").slider({
>    min: 0,
>    max: 86400,
>    step: 300, // 300s steps
>    values: [initialTime1, initialTime2], 
>    range: true, // two sides
>    create: function(event,ui){
>             valtooltip($(this),ui);
>    },
>    slide: function(event,ui){
>             valtooltip($(this),ui);
>         // values for hidden inputs
>         for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
>         //values for tooltip 0 and 1
>         $(".sliderValue[data-index=" + i + "]").val( ui.values[i]);
>         //values for value in hidden inputs 
>         $(".sliderValue[data-index=" + i + "]").attr('value', ui.values[i]);
>         }
>    }, 
>    stop: function(event,ui){
>            valtooltip($(this),ui);
>    }
>  });
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ui.values[0]` to set the slider, but you need to use `.slider("values", 0)` to set when creating the control because ui.values is undefined. I made a simple fiddle to demonstrate it working this way. I added a check to the valtooltip function so that if `ui.values` is undefined, it will set the value using the `.slider("values,` way:

```
var valtooltip = function(sliderObj, ui){
    // if this is initializing, ui.values will be undefined, so set with slider values
    var sliderValue1 = (ui.values === undefined) ? sliderObj.slider("values", 0) : ui.values[0];
    var sliderValue2 = (ui.values === undefined) ? sliderObj.slider("values", 1) : ui.values[1];
    var val1 = '<span class="slider-tip">'+ sliderValue1 + '</span>';
    var val2 = '<span class="slider-tip">'+ sliderValue2 + '</span>';
    sliderObj.find('.ui-slider-handle:first').html(val1);
    sliderObj.find('.ui-slider-handle:last').html(val2);                   
};
```

Here's the fiddle, so you can try it out: https://jsfiddle.net/e6oa09kg/1/

Hope that helps. Best of luck!